# Azure IIS Memory issue...?

Tags: azure

My cloud service app deployed on windows azure seems to be taking a whopping 2GB memory!! That is the w3wp.exe process. I have checked this by remote desktop. This is under hardly any load!

I am using co-located caching with 20% of the allocated ram going to the cache. Its a medium VM with 3.5GB ram.

What could be causing this? Any pointers where to start? Its an asp.net app talking to sql azure using Entity framework.

Sql azure is in the same data center as the cloud service, I also use the storage service which is in the same data center too.

Thanks

Comment: Bit more about your app might help. Do you store lots in the Application cache, session vars etc...? Do you get the same issue in different environments such as local? Any obvious places where a memory leak can occur? Are you disposing of objects that implement IDisposable?

Comment: Yes I use the co-located cache feature of azure. In applicaition_start, I store frequently used data in the cache. This data stays in the cache for the lifetime of the appdomain. It doesn't change. 

I dont get the same issue in the local emulated environment under IIS Express. 

All Entity framework queries use the using statement.

One thing that I do do, is store the CompositionContainer in the AppDomain. The idea is that this can be used in all layers.

I can't see this being a problem but then again....

Answer (score 1):

A normal Azure WebRole does not encounter this issue, so this is something specific to your app and I don't think anybody on here can just guess at what it might be without lots of details about your application.  I think your best bet is to figure out what objects are taking up all the memory and where they are rooted.  It is likely one simple thing that can be easily fixed in your code once you know what object is consuming the memory.  Check out the following 3 blog posts for some really good walkthroughs on how to do this:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/496973.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx